# Why does `more.com` introduce a space at the end of the line?

Tags: batch

Compare these two command, which should be the same thing according to my understanding:

```
echo abc>tmp1

echo abc|more>tmp2
```

And they do, largely. `tmp2` has an extra blank line at the end, but I don't worry about that.

Now, this is a slightly more complicated case:

```
(echo abc&echo def)>tmp3

(echo abc&echo def)|more>tmp4
```

`tmp4`, in addition to having an extra blank line at the end, also has an extra space at the end of each non-empty line. How can that be? Can I present it? I currently use `sed -e 's-[ ]$--g'`, but I would like not to rely on GNUwin.

Comment: I just notice that this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747539/windows-cmd-echo-pipe-is-adding-extra-space-at-the-end-how-to-trim-it

Comment: Considering that `more` is specifically meant to be an _interactive_ tool and not redirected to file, is there any point in all of this?

Comment: @grawity: Yes. I have noticed that `(echo a&echo b) | vpncli.exe -s` does not work, while `(echo a&echo b) | more | vpncli.exe -s` does, except for those addes spaces. Compare https://superuser.com/a/930475/253137

Comment: In that case, maybe you should be asking about the behavior of vpncli.exe, not about more.com.